# python airflow Failing Tasks Indication

Tags: python, airflow

I am trying to make airflow mark tasks as failed when an exception is raised. I have saved a python script to disk which I would like to run with the BashOperator like this:

```
import sys
def myfunc(a):
    if a == True:
        return
    else:
        raise Exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        myfunc(False)
    except:
        sys.exit(1)
```

When running code like this, I would expect that I would see a red circle (indicating failure) in the Graph View since the except part is excecuted. However, I see dark green indicating that the task was a succes. Could anyone explain how to make the tasks indicate it when they failed?

Comment: I would also expect it to fail - can you include the end of the task instance logs? You should see a line containing "Command exited with return code". Also is there a reason you are using the BashOperator rather than the PythonOperator?

Comment: Make sure that your BashOperator uses `set -e` (exit on any command) if the python script is not the last command it runs. +1 to using a PythonOperator if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can always raise AirflowException to indicate the failure of the task. Hope it helps.

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
raise AirflowException("error msg")
```